# MYSQL - Cannot joins properly with Group By 2 Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables to do 2 query with group by 2 columns. But when I try to join(left/inner) query 1 and query 2, it results me duplicates and exceed more rows than expected.Previously I join the query with group by 1 columns with no problem.The database is quite big so I leave it [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jR1CUdV1784vtJtxwSjJ1AqBfpn03901).

Query 1 (42 Records):

```
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
     date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR' 
GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
```

Query 2 (37 Records) :

```
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
   date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND month(date1) <= month('2018-06-11')
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR' 

GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
```

Query 1&2 Joins (253 Records) :

```
SELECT a.q1,a.q2,a.q3,a.q4,a.cn,a.gc,a.ct,b.q1,b.q2,b.q3,b.q4
FROM
(
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
     date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR' 
GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
)a
inner join
(
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
   date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND month(date1) <= month('2018-06-11')
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR'   
GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
)b on a.cn=b.cn
```

Comment: If these two queries are giving independent results, then you should use UNION instead of joining these queries. Otherwise you will need to post a minimal sample data with expected output and your query output showing duplicate results

Comment: I had tried union but it is not the proper way to display my result. I need to separate it by date(by quarter year). I still figure out how to post minimal sample data but it seems many data involves. If possible, can I select two different date from 1 query like the date query above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use all three columns on join clause like a.cn=b.cn and a.ct=b.ct and a.gc=b.gc

```
SELECT a.q1,a.q2,a.q3,a.q4,a.cn,a.gc,a.ct,b.q1,b.q2,b.q3,b.q4
FROM
(
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
     date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR' 
GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
)a
inner join
(
SELECT custlist.Custcat as cn,itmnocate.GradeCategory as gc,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (1,2,3)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (4,5,6)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (7,8,9)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date1) in (10,11,12)  THEN dt2.quantity/1000 ELSE NULL END) AS Q4
FROM (
SELECT 
    date1,region,quantity,unit,customeracc,location,item,
    (CASE WHEN (data2.region = 'central' OR data2.region = 'eastern' OR data2.region = 'northern' OR data2.region = 'southern' )
    THEN CONCAT('PENINSULAR',' ',data2.customeracc)
    WHEN (data2.region = 'kota kinabalu' OR data2.region = 'lahad datu' OR data2.region = 'sandakan' OR data2.region = 'tawau' )
    THEN CONCAT('SABAH',' ',data2.customeracc)
    ELSE concat('SARAWAK',' ',data2.customeracc) END) vlookrefdata 
FROM data2
) dt2
  INNER JOIN custlist on dt2.vlookrefdata = custlist.Vlookref 
  INNER JOIN itmnocate ON dt2.item = itmnocate.ItemNumber
WHERE
   date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND month(date1) <= month('2018-06-11')
  AND
   dt2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   dt2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')  
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'JV Cos'
  AND
   custlist.Area = 'PENINSULAR'   
GROUP BY itmnocate.GradeCategory,custlist.Custcat
)b on a.cn=b.cn and a.ct=b.ct and a.gc=b.gc
```

Comment: Thx it seems work for me..I never thought to join that 3 columns.Before this I just join it by 1 column.